# i want to create a chrome extension for data entry automation below are the given screenshot of a webpage and copy and paste data in that textbox

Tags: css, google-chrome, copy, paste, scrape

[[enter image description here][1]this is the main extension code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfBS4.jpg)

its scraoe the dafa form inspect tab and finds the textbox id that data has been put into

```
function scrapeData() {
  // Find the <span> tag you want to scrape data from
  const dataTag = document.querySelector("label.copyname span");
  // Extract the data from the tag
  const data = dataTag.innerText;
  // Find the textbox you want to paste the data into
  const textbox = document.querySelector(".form-control input[type='text']");
  // Paste the data into the textbox
  textbox.value = data;
}
```

Comment: Please could you clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: pls look at the image

Comment: i want that data from that line to a textbox using chrome extension